# How do i alphabetize a text file of books by author

Tags: python-3.x

```
infile = open("Test100.txt","r")
lines = infile.readlines()
lines.sort()
print("Alphabetical by Title\n")
for line in lines:
    print(line)
```

I was able to print alphabetically by title which gave me(list is longer but here are a couple):
A Christmas Carol in Prose; Being a Ghost Story of Christmas by Charles Dickens (6194)

A Doll's House : a play by Henrik Ibsen (10282)

A Modest Proposal by Jonathan Swift (7610)

A Study in Scarlet by Arthur Conan Doyle (5909)

A Tale of Two Cities by Charles Dickens (12676)

As i'm trying to alphabetize by last-name,first-name,middle-name(if present) or initial(s).How would I go to get around books that have two authors?

Also is there a simple way in python to number my output?

Here is a sample of how it is organized in the text file:

```
Pride and Prejudice by Jane Austen (39395)
Adventures of Huckleberry Finn by Mark Twain (29760)
The Yellow Wallpaper by Charlotte Perkins Gilman (29382)
Beowulf (28881)
Alice's Adventures in Wonderland by Lewis Carroll (28474)
The Prince by Niccolò Machiavelli (19347)
The Adventures of Sherlock Holmes by Arthur Conan Doyle (18868)
Metamorphosis by Franz Kafka (18428)
Grimms' Fairy Tales by Jacob Grimm and Wilhelm Grimm (17271)
Les Misérables by Victor Hugo (15149)
```

Comment: What is the syntax of the sentences when you have two authors?

Comment: Also do all names have at most 3 words in them?

Comment: Please post a sample of the lines in `Test100.txt`

Comment: Here is a sample of how it is organized in the text file:Pride and Prejudice by Jane Austen (39395)
Adventures of Huckleberry Finn by Mark Twain (29760)
The Yellow Wallpaper by Charlotte Perkins Gilman (29382)
Beowulf (28881)
Alice's Adventures in Wonderland by Lewis Carroll (28474)
The Prince by Niccolò Machiavelli (19347)
The Adventures of Sherlock Holmes by Arthur Conan Doyle (18868)
Metamorphosis by Franz Kafka (18428)
Grimms' Fairy Tales by Jacob Grimm and Wilhelm Grimm (17271)
Les Misérables by Victor Hugo (15149)

Comment: Dude, please edit it into your post. Formatting is lost in a comment

Comment: Alright there you go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re
def cmpauthors(b1,b2):
    a1 = re.search("by (.*) \(\d+\)", b1)
    if a1 == None:
        return -1
    a2 = re.search("by (.*) \(\d+\)", b2)
    if a2 == None:
        return 1
    return cmp(a1.group(1),a2.group(1))

infile = open("Test100.txt","r")
lines = infile.readlines()
lines.sort(cmp=cmpauthors)
print("Alphabetical by Authors\n")
for line in lines:
    print(line)
```

Comment: I tried using this and then printing it but i got a function error.

Comment: you have to import re, it's the regular expression module, did that fix it?

Comment: I did that but i still get this <function cmpauthors at 0x023ACA08>

Comment: Thats exactly what i get.

Comment: I see that The Beowulf book has no author, so that's gonna cause a problem in the code, change the cmpauthors function as above, I've edited the answer